# is it possible to install boost 1.55 on fedora 20 without breaking dependencies to existing boost 1.54?

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, packages

I must switch from boost and boost-devel 1.54 to 1.55 due to a bug in 1.54 on a fedora 20 x86_64 machine and I wonder what's the preferred way.

There are some packages that rely on boost (source-highlight vinagre qemu and others) which I still need and I'd really like to keep them handled by the package system.

Is there a way to accomplish this e.g. by removing boost 1.54 and building/installing 1.55 from source and mark boost-1.54 as still installed?

Or are there boost-devel packages out there which can be used instead of the stock boost 1.54 installation?

Comment: Is the goal to have everything use Boost v 1.55 or do you just need v 1.55 for an individual app/library that you are building from source?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to modify/repackage the Fedora Boost RPMs to change the installation directory. This way you will be able to keep Boost 1.54 as the system installed Boost but have a newer version around to compile/link your own applications.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879840/how-to-build-deploy-rpms-for-new-boost-version-on-rhel